# How to display values comming from json into a list

Tags: android, json, listview

I m making an Job Search application in which user enters what he is requied and then from the web service i get an json which contains all the info the user needs.Now this info i am storing in an Object.But when i call the object in the list class i get null values.

SearchValues.Java

```
public class SearchValues {

    public String address,applications,counts,contactInfo,email,expSummary,gender,IjobReqId,area,city,code,country,description,expDate,hours,state,status,title,type,maxExp,minExp,noOfPos,postedon,religion,requestorName,category;
}
```

SearchJobs.java

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute (s);
            SearchValues values = new SearchValues ();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                if (NewDataSet == null) {
                    Toast.makeText (SearchJobs.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                    values.address = table.getString ("Address");
                    values.applications = table.getString ("Applications");
                    values.counts = table.getString ("Candidate_Counts");
                    values.contactInfo = table.getString ("Contact_No");
                    values.email = table.getString ("Email");
                    values.expSummary = table.getString ("Exp_Summary");
                    values.gender = table.getString ("Gender_Name");
                    values.IjobReqId = table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID");
                    values.area = table.getString ("Job_Area");
                    values.category = table.getString ("Job_Category");
                    values.city = table.getString ("Job_City");
                    values.code = table.getString ("Job_Code");
                    values.country = table.getString ("Job_Country");
                    values.description = table.getString ("Job_Desc");
                    values.expDate = table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date");
                    values.hours = table.getString ("Job_Hours");
                    values.state = table.getString ("Job_State");
                    values.status = table.getString ("Job_Status");
                    values.title = table.getString ("Job_Title");
                    values.type = table.getString ("Job_Type");
                    values.maxExp = table.getString ("Max_Exp");
                    values.minExp = table.getString ("Min_Exp");
                    values.noOfPos = table.getString ("No_Of_Pos");
                    values.postedon = table.getString ("Posted_On");
                    values.religion = table.getString ("Religion_Name");
                    values.requestorName = table.getString ("Requestor_Name");

                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray tablearray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");
                    for (int i = 0; i <tablearray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject table = tablearray.getJSONObject (i);
                        values.address = table.getString ("Address");
                        values.applications = table.getString ("Applications");
                        values.counts = table.getString ("Candidate_Counts");
                        values.contactInfo = table.getString ("Contact_No");
                        values.email = table.getString ("Email");
                        values.expSummary = table.getString ("Exp_Summary");
                        values.gender = table.getString ("Gender_Name");
                        values.IjobReqId = table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID");
                        values.area = table.getString ("Job_Area");
                        values.category = table.getString ("Job_Category");
                        values.city = table.getString ("Job_City");
                        values.code = table.getString ("Job_Code");
                        values.country = table.getString ("Job_Country");
                        values.description = table.getString ("Job_Desc");
                        values.expDate = table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date");
                        values.hours = table.getString ("Job_Hours");
                        values.state = table.getString ("Job_State");
                        values.status = table.getString ("Job_Status");
                        values.title = table.getString ("Job_Title");
                        values.type = table.getString ("Job_Type");
                        values.maxExp = table.getString ("Max_Exp");
                        values.minExp = table.getString ("Min_Exp");
                        values.noOfPos = table.getString ("No_Of_Pos");
                        values.postedon = table.getString ("Posted_On");
                        values.religion = table.getString ("Religion_Name");
                        values.requestorName = table.getString ("Requestor_Name");

                    }


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent (SearchJobs.this, SearchJobsList.class);
            startActivity (i);
        }
    }
```

SearchJobsLists.java

```
public class SearchJobsCustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    SearchValues values=new SearchValues ();

    public SearchJobsCustomList(Context c) {
        super();
        this.c = c;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(view==null){
            view= LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists,viewGroup,false);
            TextView JobCode= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_job_code);
            TextView Category= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_category);
            TextView ExpYrs= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
            TextView ExpMnths= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
            TextView Date= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_date);


            JobCode.setText (values.code);
            Category.setText (values.category);
            ExpYrs.setText (values.minExp);
            ExpMnths.setText (values.maxExp);
            Date.setText (values.postedon);





        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Json Response

```
 { "NewDataSet": { "Table": [ {"Address": "Kurla,Mumbai,Maharashtra,INDIA", "Applications": "2", "Candidate_Counts": "0", "Contact_No": "9896969696", "Email": "sagar@gmail.com", "Exp_Summary": "test", "Gender_Name": "Male", "IJob_Request_ID": "1", "Job_Area": "Kurla", "Job_Category": "Caretaker", "Job_City": "Mumbai", "Job_Code": "J-111", "Job_Country": "INDIA", "Job_Desc": "Caretaker", "Job_Exp_Date": "27 Jun 2014", "Job_Hours": "8.00", "Job_State": "Maharashtra", "Job_Status": "Open", "Job_Title": "Caretaker", "Job_Type": "Permanent", "Max_Exp": "0.60", "Min_Exp": "0.00", "No_Of_Pos": "5", "Posted_On": "13 Jun 2014", "Religion_Name": "Hindu", "Requestor_Name": "sagar shinde" }, {"Address": "Chembur,Mumbai,Maharashtra,INDIA", "Applications": "0", "Candidate_Counts": "0", "Contact_No": "9896969696", "Email": "sagar@gmail.com", "Exp_Summary": "test", "Gender_Name": "Male", "IJob_Request_ID": "2", "Job_Area": "Chembur", "Job_Category": "Caretaker", "Job_City": "Mumbai", "Job_Code": "j-112", "Job_Country": "INDIA", "Job_Desc": "need Caretaker", "Job_Exp_Date": "27 Jun 2014", "Job_Hours": "8.00", "Job_State": "Maharashtra", "Job_Status": "Open", "Job_Title": "Caretaker", "Job_Type": "Permanent", "Max_Exp": "0.60", "Min_Exp": "0.00", "No_Of_Pos": "5", "Posted_On": "13 Jun 2014", "Religion_Name": "Hindu", "Requestor_Name": "sagar shinde" } ] }}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but using GSON will make the conversion from Json to Objects much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is.. I am assuming that may be the problem with setting the data.. 
Here I am giving the sample what i used

```
 public class StageArray {

    private JSONArray data = new JSONArray();

   public JSONArray getData() {
       return data;
       }
   public void setData(JSONArray data) {
       this.data = data;
       }

   private static final StageArray holder = new StageArray();
   public static StageArray getInstance() {
       return holder;
       }
   }
```

When ever I am set the data i will call

```
StageArray.getInstance().setData(JSONObject );
```

for getting

```
stageArray = StageArray.getInstance().getData();
```

Try by this... Hope it will work

**EDIT:**

I worked around this and **GOT it WORKED**
 I updated **StageArray**  code check it before going to next lines

**In else if condition changed to**

```
else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray tablearray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");
                StageArray.getInstance().setData(tablearray);
             }
```

And Change the **getView** Function

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(view==null){
            view= LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists,viewGroup,false);

            TextView Category= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_category);
            TextView ExpYrs= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
            TextView ExpMnths= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
            TextView Date= (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_date);

            JSONArray stageArray = StageArray.getInstance().getData();

            for (int j = 0; j < stageArray.length(); j++) {
                 try {
                    JSONObject c = stageArray.getJSONObject(j);
                     Category.setText (c.getString("Job_Category"));
                      ExpYrs.setText (c.getString("Min_Exp"));
                      ExpMnths.setText (c.getString("Max_Exp"));
                      Date.setText (c.getString("Posted_On"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            }
        return view;
    }
```

If it works.. just approve this ans.

Comment: @user3667909 are using SearchJobsCustomList inside SearchJobsLists ?

Comment: @user3667909 is seams data is coming like array.. so every iteration values are adding but while getting you are not using what position what data is needed.. it seams so where missed the concept of position.. check the full flow once

Answer (score 1):

Because I don't know your data,I'm not sure what the problem is...In my opinion,may be some of your data is empty.    For example, somebody don't have an address.In this case:

```
values.address = table.getString ("Address");
```

This code will throw a JSONException,and values will be null.So I suggest you to use [optString (String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
values.address = table.optString ("Address");
```

The same as above,replace all JSONObject.getXXXX() to JSONOBject.optXXXX() may help.

Comment: my json is getting parsed correctly and also the info is geting stored in values bt when i call it in list view i am not getting anuthing